# Package manager doesn't see internal NuGet packages published before today

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-server

We have an internal NuGet package feed (published from TeamCity), and after updating VS2015 NuGet Package Manager as prompted by VS, I can't see any packages in the feed that were published before the NuGet Package Manager update.

I can navigate to the feed URL and see all the expected packages in the resulting xml (proving that the packages do exist on the server), but they do not show up when browsing the internal feed in NuGet Package Manager.  Packages published since the update do appear when browsing.

I did not have this problem in VS2015 before this update (now on NuGet Package Manager version 3.4.2).  My co-workers using VS2013 are able to see all the packages as expected.

Comment: From the server where your feed is hosted.  Are the packages still there?

Comment: Yes, as noted (and now clarified in parentheses) I can see all the expected packages by navigating to <feedServerUrl>/nuget/Packages

Comment: Ran into this issue again immediately after installing the update MS just pushed for VS 2015.3 - packages published before I installed the update (i.e. almost everything) didn't appear in the NuGet Manager Solution tab, but opening NuGet Manager at the project level DOES show all previously published packages.